# Induction divisibility proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility

Prove that $4^n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom nk +14n-1 $ is divisible by $7$ for every $n \geq 1$.

***Basic Step***: For $n=1$, $21$ is divisible by $7$.($21 \mod 7 = 0$)

***Induction Hypothesis***: Suppose that for an arbitrarily chosen $n \geq 1$ the number $4^n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom nk +14n-1 $ is divisible by $7$.

***Induction Step***: We will show that $4^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1}k +14(n+1)-1 $ is divisible by 7.
\begin{align*}
4^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1}k +14(n+1)-1 &= 4 \times 4^n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}+\binom{n+1}{n} +14n+14-1 \\
&=4 \times 4^n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}+(n+1) +14n+14-1 \\
&= 4 \times 4^n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}+14n-1+(n+1)+14 
\end{align*}

So from the hypothesis we made the first term is divisible by 7. How can i show that the rest is divisible by 7? Also I am not sure if my approach is correct!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can you be a little more specific please?

Comment: I don't understand why people keep using congruence questions to try to teach induction proofs, when induction is rarely a method of choice for such questions (and it is not for this particular one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing arithmetic modulo $\;7\;$ :

$$4^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk+14n-1=4^n\cdot2^n+14n-1=4^{n-1}2^{n-1}\cdot8+14(n-1)+14-1=$$

$$=\overbrace{\color{red}{4^{n-1}2^{n-1}+14(n-1)-1}}^{=0\;,\;\text{by Ind. Hypot.}}+\underbrace{7\left(4^{n-1}2^{n-1}+2\right)}_{=0\;\text{trivially}}$$

and we're done.

Observe that "$=0$" above means the expression equals zero modulo $\;7\;$ , i.e.: it is divisible by seven.

Comment: So according to your answer i did the following and correct me if I'm wrong. For n+1, i get to the point where 8^(n+1) +14(n+1)-1 = 8*8^n+14n+14-1 = 8^n+14n-1 + 7(8^n+14n+2).

Comment: Well, that seems to wrap it all, @CharisAlex...if *indeed* you did that. Since you didn't simplify that summation to $\;2^n\;$ I didn't read it all.

Comment: Note also that writing $8^n=(7+1)^n\equiv1^n=1\pmod7$ one does not need induction at all.